# pausing the execution of a program in processing 3

Tags: java, processing

I'm trying to create a pause button in processing as follows:

```
boolean paused = false;  
void mouseClicked(){
  if(!paused)
    stop();
  else
    start();
  paused = !paused;
}
```

It stops the program but does not start it when I press again. what's wrong here? thanks in advance.

Comment: Nothing in the code snippet seems to obviously be causing the problem. Are you sure your `stop()` or `start()` methods don't change the value of `paused`?

Comment: they are built in methods.

Comment: Assuming those methods work. Are `start()` and `stop()` methods blocking? If they are blocking, then the condition may be being checked before the completion of the previous execution. If this is the case, you may need to move `paused = !paused;` to the beginning of the method, then negate your condition check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very hard to help you without seeing a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Specifically, we have no idea what your `start()` and `stop()` functions are doing.

But generally, I'd say you're on the right track. You'd use a `paused` variable to keep track of whether the application was paused, and then only run your program when `paused` is false. Here's a skeleton:

```
boolean paused = false;

void draw(){
   if(paused){
      //draw paused screen
   }
   else{
      //draw your program
   }
}

void mouseClicked(){
   paused = !paused;
}
```

You might also look into using the `noLoop()` and `loop()` functions.

Comment: the loop() and noLoop() methods work perfectly, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean paused = false;

void setup() {
  size (100, 100);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  text(str(frameCount), 5, 15);
}

void mouseClicked() { // click event, outside draw()!
  paused = !paused;
  if (paused) {
    noLoop(); // stops the draw() loop
  } else {
    loop(); // restarts the draw() loop
  }
}
```